# How to call a function that calls other functions on chrome.scripting.executeScript

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm trying to call an external function inside the function passed in the 'func' parameter in the chrome.scripting.executeScript call:

```
await chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: {tabId: tabId},
    func: async () => {
        //call a extern function here
    }
})
```

In this call i get 'ReferenceError: [function name] is not defined'

I would like to know if it is possible, and if so, how is it possible?

Comment: You need to inject all of the code inside this function, literally inside.

Comment: I even realized that. But I wanted to find some way to "pull" all the necessary code without necessarily putting it inside

Comment: Well, you can't.

Comment: Any pointers on why we can't @wOxxOm

Comment: Because this is not implemented. This API simply takes func.toString() and sends it into the tab.

Comment: Same problem. @wOxxOm besides call this function too.

Answer (score -1):

In the context of using `chrome.scripting.executeScript`, the function passed in the `func` parameter is executed in the content script environment, which is isolated from the extension's background script and any other scripts on the webpage. As a result, you cannot directly call an external function defined in the extension's background script from the content script environment.

However, there are ways to achieve communication between the content script and the background script. One common approach is to use `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` and `chrome.runtime.onMessage` to send messages between the content script and the background script.

Here's an example of how you can use messaging to call an external function defined in the background script from the content script:

background.js:

```js
// Define the external function in the background script
function externalFunction(argument) {
  console.log("External function called from content script with argument:", argument);
  return "Response from background!";
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (message.action === "callExternalFunction") {
    const result = externalFunction(message.argument);
    sendResponse(result);
  }
});
```

contentScript.js:

```js
// Send a message to the background script to call the external function with an argument
chrome.scripting.executeScript({
  target: { tabId: tabId },
  func: () => {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
      action: "callExternalFunction",
      argument: "Hello from content script!"
    }, function(response) {
      console.log("Response from background script:", response);
    });
  }
});
```

Remember to declare the `"background"` permission in your manifest.json to allow communication between content scripts and the background script:

manifest.json:

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Your Extension Name",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Your extension description",
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "scripting",
    "background"
  ],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

In this example, the content script sends a message to the background script with an argument using `chrome.runtime.sendMessage`. The background script listens for messages using `chrome.runtime.onMessage` and, when it receives the message with the specified action, it calls the `externalFunction` with the provided `argument`.

After processing the function with the argument, the background script sends back a response using the `sendResponse` function, which will be received in the content script as a parameter of the callback function.

The console output in the content script will show the response received from the background script.

This way, you can effectively communicate between content scripts and the background script, including calling functions defined in the background script from the content script and passing arguments back and forth.

[image: communicate between content scripts and the background script]